# Finding the analytical solution of a first order system with pure time delay

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inverse-laplace, delay-differential-equations

I have a simple system and I am searching for the solution for f(t):

$$\frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial t} = c_1 \left( f(t) + g(t) + c_2 \right)$$.

It turns out that, in this system $g$ can be related to $f$ by a pure time delay:

$$g(t) = f(t-a)u(t-a)$$

where $u(t)$ is the Heaviside function.

Applying the Laplace transform to the equation above and isolating $F(s)$ leads to:

$$F(s) = \frac{f(0) + c_1c_2}{s - c_1(1 - e^{-as})}$$.

Since there is a complex exponential at the denominator I cannot use the inverse Laplace transform nor break this into partial fractions.

How can one find the solution of such an equation?

If I cannot directly resolve the equation, can I infer a given solution (from the numerical integration of this system) and identify the coefficients?

If the analytical solution does not exists, is there a proof that explains why?

Comment: Are you able to solve the homoegeneous DDE, $f' = c_1(f(t) + f(t-a))$?

Comment: Are you aware of the existence of [Delay differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation)?

Answer (score 1):

Applying the Laplace transform to

$$\frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial t} = c_1 \left( f(t) + f(t-a)u(t-a) + c_2 \right)$$.

and assuming $f(t)=0,\ t < a$, we got

$$
F(s) = -\frac{((c_1c_2+s f_0)e^{as})}{s(c_1+(c_1-s)e^{as})}=-\frac{c_1c_2+s f_0}{s(c_1e^{-a s}+c_1-s)}=\frac{c_1c_2+s f_0}{s(s-c_1)(1-\frac{c_1e^{-as}}{s-c_1})}
$$

and now making

$$
\frac{1}{(1-\frac{c_1e^{-as}}{c_1-s})}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{c_1e^{-as}}{s-c_1}\right)^k
$$

we can invert $F(s)\to f(t)$.

Note that the series is convergent for $|c_1e^{-as}|<|s-c_1|$ and

$$
\frac{c_1c_2+s f_0}{s(s-c_1)}=\frac{c_2+f_0}{s-c_1}-\frac{c_2}{s}
$$

and

$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{\left(\frac{c_1e^{-as}}{s-c_1}\right)^k}{s-c_1}\right]=\frac{c_1^k \left(\left(\left(1-\frac{t}{a k}\right)^k-1\right)(-a k)^k\right) e^{c_1 (t-a k)} u (t-a
   k)}{k!}
$$

Follows a MATHEMATICA script showing the approximation accuracy for `n = 4` in blue and the precise integration in dashed red

```
n = 4;
parms = {c1 -> -1, c2 -> 1, a -> 2, f0 -> 0};
sum = Sum[((c1 Exp[-a s])/(s - c1))^k, {k, 0, n}];
tmax = (n+1) a /. parms;
Fs = (c1 c2 + s f0)/(s (s - c1)) sum /. parms;
ft = InverseLaplaceTransform[Fs, s, t];
gr1 = Plot[ft, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All];
ode = f'[t] - c1 (f[t] + f[t - a] + c2);
ode0 = {ode == 0, f[0] == f0} /. parms;
ft = Quiet@NDSolve[ode0, f, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];
gr2 = Plot[Evaluate[f[t] /. ft], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}, PlotRange -> All];
Show[gr1, gr2]
```

[image]

Comment: You might elaborate on the conditions under which your initial series expansion is valid.

Comment: For the case study, the condition is $e^{-2 x}-x^2-2 x-y^2-1\le 0$. Here $s = x + i y$ giving as feasible a region containing the right Argand-Gauss semi plane. Supposedly $a > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

##### Solving

The differential equation is a linear DDE of order one with a non-constant coefficient. We can get rid of this one by splitting the DDE into two intervals:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}f\left( t \right)}{\operatorname{d}t} &= c_{1} \cdot \left( f\left( t \right) + f\left( t - a \right) \cdot \theta\left( t - a \right) + c_{2} \right)\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}f\left( t \right)}{\operatorname{d}t} &= c_{1} \cdot f\left( t \right) + c_{1} \cdot f\left( t - a \right) \cdot \theta\left( t - a \right) + c_{1} \cdot c_{2}\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}f\left( t \right)}{\operatorname{d}t} &= \begin{cases}
c_{1} \cdot f\left( t \right) + c_{1} \cdot c_{2}, &\text{for } t < a\\
c_{1} \cdot f\left( t \right) + c_{1} \cdot f\left( t - a \right) + c_{1} \cdot c_{2}, &\text{for } t \geq a\\
\end{cases}\\
\end{align*}

Now there are two linear DEs of order $1$ but constant coefficients. We can trivially for $t < a$ (because it's an order $1$ ODE) where $c$ can be any constant:
\begin{align*}
f\left( t \right) &= c \cdot e^{c_{1} \cdot t} - c_{2}\\
\end{align*}

For $t \geq a$ we could say $f\left( t \right) = g\left( t \right) + b$. We would get:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}g\left( t \right)}{\operatorname{d}t} &= c_{1} \cdot g\left( t \right) + c_{1} \cdot g\left( t - a \right) + 2 \cdot c_{1} \cdot b + c_{1} \cdot c_{2}\\
\end{align*}

If $b = -\tfrac{1}{2} \cdot c_{2}$ we get a homogeneous DDE:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}g\left( t \right)}{\operatorname{d}t} &= c_{1} \cdot g\left( t \right) + c_{1} \cdot g\left( t - a \right)\\
\end{align*}

Substituting $g\left( t \right) = e^{\lambda \cdot t}$ we get:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}e^{\lambda \cdot t}}{\operatorname{d}t} &= c_{1} \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t} + c_{1} \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot \left( t - a \right)}\\
\lambda \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t} &= c_{1} \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t} + c_{1} \cdot e^{\lambda \cdot t} \cdot e^{-\lambda \cdot a}\\
\lambda &= c_{1} + c_{1} \cdot e^{-\lambda \cdot a}\\
\end{align*}

This is an classical equation wich can be solved via the [Lambert W-function](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog2/):
\begin{align*}
\lambda &= c_{1} + c_{1} \cdot e^{-a \cdot \lambda} \tag{$-c_{1}$}\\
\lambda - c_{1} &= c_{1} \cdot e^{-a \cdot \lambda}\\
\lambda - c_{1} &= c_{1} \cdot e^{-a \cdot c_{1} - a \cdot \left( \lambda - c_{1} \right)} \tag{$\cdot e^{a \cdot \left( \lambda - c_{1} \right)}$}\\
\left( \lambda - c_{1} \right) \cdot e^{a \cdot \left( \lambda - c_{1} \right)} &= c_{1} \cdot e^{-a \cdot c_{1}} \tag{$\cdot a$}\\
a \cdot \left( \lambda - c_{1} \right) \cdot e^{a \cdot \left( \lambda - c_{1} \right)} &= a \cdot c_{1} \cdot e^{-a \cdot c_{1}} \tag{$\operatorname{W}_{k}\left( \cdot \right)$}\\
a \cdot \left( \lambda - c_{1} \right) &= \operatorname{W}_{k}\left( a \cdot c_{1} \cdot e^{-a \cdot c_{1}} \right) \tag{$\div a$ then $+ c_{1}$}\\
\lambda &= \frac{1}{a} \cdot \operatorname{W}_{k}\left( a \cdot c_{1} \cdot e^{-a \cdot c_{1}} \right) + c_{1}\\
\end{align*}
where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So:

\begin{align*}
f\left( t \right) = \begin{cases}
c \cdot e^{c_{1} \cdot t} - c_{2}, &\text{for } t < a\\
e^{\left( \frac{1}{a} \cdot \operatorname{W}_{k}\left( a \cdot c_{1} \cdot e^{-a \cdot c_{1}} \right) + c_{1} \right) \cdot t} - \frac{c_{2}}{2}, &\text{for } t \geq a\\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

or
$$\fbox{$\begin{align*}
f\left( t \right) = \begin{cases}
c \cdot e^{c_{1} \cdot t} - c_{2}, &\text{for } t < a\\
\sum\limits_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}\left[ d_{k} \cdot e^{\left( \frac{1}{a} \cdot \operatorname{W}_{k}\left( a \cdot c_{1} \cdot e^{-a \cdot c_{1}} \right) + c_{1} \right) \cdot t} \right] - \frac{c_{2}}{2}, &\text{for } t \geq a\\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$}$$
where $d_{k} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ (after all, the terms with the Lambert W-function are homogeneous solutions and there are infinitely many in both directions).

In Mathematica you could check the solution $g\left( t \right)$ and it's values like this:

```
g[t_] := Subscript[d, 1] Exp[(1/a LambertW[k, a Subscript[c, 1] Exp[-a Subscript[c, 1]]] + Subscript[c, 1]) t];
Subscript[c, 1]:= 1; Subscript[c, 2] := 20; Subscript[d, 1] := 2; k := 1; a := 1; x := 20;
N[g'[x] == Subscript[c, 1] g[x] + Subscript[c, 1] g[x - a]]
```

[It gives you the output `True`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx9PP.png) For some reason this is not the case when adding the constant term in the DE an the functional equation even if it has to be so.